# I want to create a countdown timer and as soon as the timer finishes i want a another countdown timer to run

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start()
```

> this helps me create a timer but how can i create a timer as soon as
>   the above timer finishes and generate a notification when the timer
>   finishes

Answer (score 1):

First : Make a class that extends CountDownTimer

```
public class SecondTimer extends CountDownTimer{

        public SecondTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        //Generate notification here
        }
    }
```

Second : Initialize the instance of that class

```
SecondTimer secondTimer = new SecondTimer(5000,1000);
```

Third : Start SecondTimer when First timer stops

```
public class FirstTimer extends CountDownTimer{

        public SecondTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        secondTimer.start();
        }
    }


FirstTimer firstTimer = new FirstTimer(5000,1000);
firstTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define the CountDownTimer as an anonymous class, but instead in its own file. Then you could just call: new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) to start it in the onFinish() method of the previous one. Foer the notification, you could e. g. use Toasts or Snackbars.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
package com.stackoverflow.example;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;

/**
 * @author aminu on 5/7/2016.
 */
public class CountDownTimerHelper {

    private int numOfRuns;
    private long millisInFuture, countDownInterval;


    private CountDownTimerHelper(int numOfRuns, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        //you may check for invalid arguments here like negative intervals

        this.numOfRuns = numOfRuns;
        this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
        this.countDownInterval = countDownInterval;
    }

    private void tryRun() {
        if (numOfRuns-- > 0) {
            new CountDownTimerImpl(millisInFuture, countDownInterval).start();
        }
    }


    public static void startCountDownTimers(int numOfRuns, long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        new CountDownTimerHelper(numOfRuns, millisInFuture, countDownInterval).tryRun();
    }

    private class CountDownTimerImpl extends CountDownTimer {
        /**
         * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
         *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
         *                          is called.
         * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
         *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
         */
        private CountDownTimerImpl(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //notify user countdown ended by showing toast or something like that

            //mTextField.setText("done " + "remaining " + numOfRuns + ");

            tryRun();
        }

    }
}
```

then to use it just do `CountDownTimerHelper.startCountDownTimers(numOfRuns,yourDuration,yourInterval)`

**example**
`CountDownTimerHelper.startCountDownTimers(5,15000,1000) //this will run 5 successive countdowntimers with duration 15 seconds and interval 1 second`